# What is the difference between int, nativeint, int64, and int32?

Tags: types, integer, ocaml

[According to the manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.14/htmlman/lex.html#sss:integer-literals), OCaml has 4 kinds of integer literals:

```
integer-literal ::= [-] (0…9) { 0…9 ∣ _ }
    ∣    [-] (0x ∣ 0X) (0…9 ∣ A…F ∣ a…f) { 0…9 ∣ A…F ∣ a…f ∣ _ }
    ∣    [-] (0o ∣ 0O) (0…7) { 0…7 ∣ _ }
    ∣    [-] (0b ∣ 0B) (0…1) { 0…1 ∣ _ }
 
int32-literal   ::=  integer-literal l
 
int64-literal   ::=  integer-literal L
 
nativeint-literal   ::=  integer-literal n
```

Inspecting the types of these literals (using utop) gives the following results:

- `123 : int`
- `123l : int32`
- `123L : int64`
- `123n : nativeint`

The meaning of `int32` and `int64` is obvious enough, but what is the difference between `int` and `nativeint`, and how do they relate to the explicitly sized 32/64 bit ints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in various sections of the manual and standard library documentation:

[Integer numbers](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.14/htmlman/values.html#sss:values:integer):

> Integer values are integer numbers from −2<sup>30</sup> to 2<sup>30</sup>−1, that is −1073741824 to 1073741823. The implementation may support a wider range of integer values: on 64-bit platforms, the current implementation supports integers ranging from −2<sup>62</sup> to 2<sup>62</sup>−1.

And the manual section on [interfacing with C](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/intfc.html#s:c-value) also gives some useful context to this:

> An object of type value is either:
>
> - an unboxed integer;
> - or a pointer to a block inside the heap, allocated through one of the `caml_alloc_*` functions described in section 20.4.4.

> Integer values encode 63-bit signed integers (31-bit on 32-bit architectures). They are unboxed (unallocated).

It is because one bit is used to distinguish between unboxed integers and pointers that regular `int`s are either 31 or 63-bit values.

[Int32](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Int32.html):

> 32-bit integers.
>
> This module provides operations on the type `int32` of signed 32-bit integers. Unlike the built-in `int` type, the type `int32` is guaranteed to be exactly 32-bit wide on all platforms. All arithmetic operations over `int32` are taken modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.
>
> Performance notice: values of type `int32` occupy more memory space than values of type `int`, and arithmetic operations on `int32` are generally slower than those on `int`. Use `int32` only when the application requires exact 32-bit arithmetic.

[Int64](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Int64.html):

> 64-bit integers.
>
> This module provides operations on the type `int64` of signed 64-bit integers. Unlike the built-in `int` type, the type `int64` is guaranteed to be exactly 64-bit wide on all platforms. All arithmetic operations over int64 are taken modulo 2<sup>64</sup>
>
> Performance notice: values of type `int64` occupy more memory space than values of type `int`, and arithmetic operations on `int64` are generally slower than those on `int`. Use `int64` only when the application requires exact 64-bit arithmetic.

[Nativeint](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Nativeint.html):

> Processor-native integers.
>
> This module provides operations on the type `nativeint` of signed 32-bit integers (on 32-bit platforms) or signed 64-bit integers (on 64-bit platforms). This integer type has exactly the same width as that of a pointer type in the C compiler. All arithmetic operations over `nativeint` are taken modulo 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> depending on the word size of the architecture.
>
> Performance notice: values of type `nativeint` occupy more memory space than values of type `int`, and arithmetic operations on `nativeint` are generally slower than those on int. Use `nativeint` only when the application requires the extra bit of precision over the `int` type.